# Fatal error: Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Value for key "xsi:type" is missing

Tags: magento2, error

Suddenly got below error on magento2.1.9 platform. can someone suggest me for the same.

Server requirement are fulfilled. you can review by this URL
http://itsupply.com/info.php

```
Fatal error: Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Value for key "xsi:type" is missing in the argument data. in /home/itsupply/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Argument/Interpreter/Composite.php:54 Stack trace: 
#0 /home/itsupply/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Config/Mapper/Dom.php(102): Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\Interpreter\Composite->evaluate(Array) 
#1 /home/itsupply/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Reader/Filesystem.php(168): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Config\Mapper\Dom->convert(Object(DOMDocument)) 
#2 /home/itsupply/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Reader/Filesystem.php(127): Magento\Framework\Config\Reader\Filesystem->_readFiles(Object(Magento\Framework\Config\FileIterator)) 
#3 /home/itsupply/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ObjectManagerFactory.php(282): Magento\Framework\Config\Reader\Filesystem->read('primary') 
#4 /home/itsupply/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ObjectManagerFactory.php(142): Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManagerFactory->_loadP in /home/itsupply/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ObjectManagerFactory.php on line 284
```